# Extracting the value of nodes from xml

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, xmlnode

I have two different XML files , the first one is a template xml and the second one is the actual xml. The template xml contains only the elements where as the actual xml contains some of the elements present in template xml as shown below in the xml files . For each element present in the template xml i want to look at the actual xml and see if that element is present and if so then extract its value and print or else just print empty space as shown in the output

Template.xml

```
<personinfo>
   <person>
     <name><name>
     <age></age>
     <address>
     <street></street>
     <city></city>
     <address>
   </person>
   <person>
     <name><name>
     <age></age>
     <address>
     <street></street>
     <city></city>
     <address>
   </person>
   <person>
     <name><name>
     <age></age>
     <address>
     <street></street>
     <city></city>
     <address>
   </person>
</personinfo>
```

Actual.xml

```
<personinfo>
   <person>
     <name>tom<name>
     <age>26</age>
     <address>
     <street>main street</street>
     <city>washington</city>
     <address>
   </person>
   <person>
     <name>mike<name>
     <age>30</age>
     <address>
     <street>first street</street>
     <city>dallas</city>
     <address>
   </person>
</personinfo>
```

Expected output

```
tom,26,main street,washington,mike,30,first street,dallas,,,,
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Show us what you've done so far and what problems you've encountered.

Comment: I have tried to parse these xml files using dom and have two seperate documents for each xml and after that i don't know how to look into the elements one by one from template xml in the actual xml and get the values ...

Comment: @Naveen what are you using to parse the xml?  Jdom - http://www.jdom.org/ is simple and easy to use.  As for getting elements one by one jdom will let you get a list of elements by calling element.getChildren.  Then for each element you can recursively call the same method.

Answer (score 2):

First you should define a schema for the XML not a template. Next you can create a java bean of a Person. That can be mapped to each person using JAXB. This has been the quickest way for me in the past to XML parsing.
http://jaxb.java.net/

Answer (score 1):

The example is quite small so this may not be an issue (yet) but I'd go for SAX instead of DOM for parsing the content of the XML. Very easy to have the events output content if found.

Read up on XML processing in JAVA for example:

- [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/xml/books/xmljava/)
- and [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/JavaTechandXML/)
- and numerous other websites and articles and books

Answer (score 0):

a. Parse both documents into a DOM

b. Recursively traverse template

c. (option 1) For each element found build up an xpath (use a stack and push/pop?)

d. (option 1) run the xpath on actual.xml

c. (option 2) Recursively traverse actual at the same time as the template. If the element is not found stop traversing deeper into the template.